# Develop and install an UWP app on Windows Server 2016

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-server-2016

I need to develop a new UWP app with FCU support (Build 16299). Using Windows 10, I have no problem. But I need to deploy the app on Windows Server 2016.
So:
- I create the package using the standard procedure in VS2017
- try to launch the cmdlet Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 on WinSrv 2016

I get an unspecified error.
If I try to downgrade the app to 10240, I have no problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the OS build of the server? is it 16299?